# Autocomplete combobox with SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server

When filling a combobox with data in database, the first row in database was missing.

```
con = new SqlConnection(cs.connetionString);
con.Open();

Sql = "SELECT * FROM ItemRate";

command = new SqlCommand(Sql, con);
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

reader.Read();

while (reader.Read())
{
    string cat = reader["RateOfInt"].ToString();
    comboBox4.Items.Add(cat);
}
```

Comment: I think it's that `reader.Read();` **before** the while loop that's causing you problems.

Comment: please help me i can't found what the problem is?

Comment: Remove the reader.Read();  which is before the whole loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    con = new SqlConnection(cs.connetionString);
    con.Open();

    Sql = "SELECT * FROM ItemRate";

    command = new SqlCommand(Sql, con);
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();



    while (reader.Read())
    {
        string cat = reader["RateOfInt"].ToString();
        comboBox4.Items.Add(cat);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Calling `reader.Read()` advances one row, so the first time you call it **before** the while loop it already lands on the first row, but then you call it again in the while condition, so it advances to the second row, just remove the call **before** the condition.

```
    con = new SqlConnection(cs.connetionString);
    con.Open();

    Sql = "SELECT * FROM ItemRate";

    command = new SqlCommand(Sql, con);
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    // remove this line
    // reader.Read();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        string cat = reader["RateOfInt"].ToString();
        comboBox4.Items.Add(cat);
    }
```

Edit: Here is the example from the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read?view=netcore-2.2#examples)